# Removing regions and items apex

Tags: apex

how to remove regions and items in apex ? I want to remove list,datepicker,clorpicker and so many other regions and items in the backend through out my application

Answer (score 0):

Open the region or item, for example by double-clicking it.
In the upper right corner you should be able to see a button "Delete".
Use it to delete the currently open region, item, whatever you have.

Comment: The method which you mentioned only deletes the regions or items, i want to remove(disable) few selected regions and items to all my developers so that he/she can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can hide your region/item at application level:

1. Go to `Region/item properties` -> `Server-side Condition` -> `Never`. That will hide the region/item for all your developers at application level (even for you.).
2. `Region/item properties` -> `Custom Attributes` -> `style="display:none;"`.
3. (For item specific only) `Item`->`Identification`->`Hidden`. Although it will reset all your settings for your list and datepicker.